# Is the solution of this differential equation a line?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having problems understanding this question which asks whether it is true or false tha there is a solution of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt} = \sin(y)$ whose graph is a line. I tried working it out and got stuck when I arrived at the equation $\ln (\csc y + \cot y) = t + c$. How am I supposed to know if this gives me a solution that is a line?

Comment: if you are looking for a  linear solution, then you should try $y = mt + c.$ see if you can determine $m, c.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Sometimes you can find more simple solutions to ODE just by, well, guessing and taking a thorough look. The equation $y = {\rm const}$ defines a horizontal line on plane $(t, y)$. Are there any such horizontal lines that are solutions of your equation?

Comment: Doesn't a horizontal line have a gradient of 0, so dy should be = 0? So that that doesn't fit the equation dy = sin(y)?

Comment: But there might be values of $y$ for which it'll fit.

Comment: Huh, sorry I don't really understand what you mean. Could you please give an example/elaboration on your answer?

Comment: Well, you started moving in the right direction. We suppose that there is a solution $y(t) \equiv C$. That's only a horizontal line, though, but let's focus only on them. On the one hand, $\frac{dy}{dt} \equiv 0$. And since it must satisfy differential equation $\sin(y(t)) \equiv 0$. Now, could you find such constant that $\sin C = 0$ ?

Comment: Ah I get it, so the solution would be $y(t) = 0$. Thanks!

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's a lot of such solutions in form $y(t) \equiv \pi * k, \; k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 1):

For example, y = pi (3.14...) is a solution as are others like it.